# How do I use another stylesheet along with Bootsttrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My main stylesheet is this one:

```
<link href="css/waldbrand.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But whenever I add a new stylesheet into my HTML file, my main CSS gets overridden.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

How do I add that Bootsttrap stylesheet into my HTML without having my main CSS overridden?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand CSS precedence, browser evaluates and applies CSS rules in below order:

1. Inline css ( html style attribute ) overrides css rules in style tag
   and css file.
2. More specific selector takes precedence over a less specific one.
3. Rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both
   have the same specificity.
4. A css rule with !important always takes precedence.

According to this you should load your custom css last, so it overrides similar styles from bootstrap. Also try to create custom CSS for specific elements. At the end, and less recommendable because it is bad  practices, use `!important`.

For further reference I recommend to take a look at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that the styles defined in your latter CSS file are overwriting the styles defined in your former CSS file.

The specific sticking points to look for are what Cristian Colorado mentioned.

I am just clarifying that it's most likely that your second link is not actually overriding the first (if you want 2 style sheets, you can, in fact, just define two different links like you have done. It's probably worth looking into to combine the styles into one sheet, but technically your css files should both be loaded). Just look more closely at your actual styles ("!important" will override styles without "!important", for example), and pay attention to which styles gets loaded last.